# What is the meaning of npm scope symbol?

Tags: npm

In the AWS [Amplify tutorial page](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/start), I saw a sub-package (cli) is installed as global package:

`npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli`

and then later the whole scope is installed as a local package:

`npm install --save aws-amplify`

Does a package (such as aws-amplify) automatically include its sub package ( @aws-amplify/cli)?

Answer (score 1):

npm scope normally indicates an organization. In this case it is an organization `@aws-amplify` that has a package named `cli`, so `@aws-amplify/cli`.

AWS Amplify at the beginning does not have many multiple packages. `aws-amplify` is the core library. Then it [modularized](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/wiki/Amplify-modularization). `aws-amplify` still remains as a wrapper around core modules, but it does not include `cli`